# How to check if a class contains null in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class

```
class Job {
  String id;
  String jobTitle;
  String updatedAt;
  String createdAt;
  Job(
      {this.id,
      this.jobTitle,
      this.updatedAt,
      this.createdAt});

  factory Job.fromMap(Map data) {
    return Job(
      id: data['id'],
      jobTitle: data['jobTitle'],
      updatedAt: data['updatedAt'],
      createdAt: data['createdAt'],
    );
  }
}
```

After assigning values:

```
Job _job = new Job();
```

For instance `_job.jobTitle = 'farmer';`

Before saving to the backend, I want to make sure there are no null values within, the _job object.

Rather than checking for each item in the object class e.g

```
If(_job.jobTitle != null && _job.updatedAt != null && ....){
}
```

How can I do a one-step check if the object class contains any null values?
Something like

```
if(_job.contains(null)){
}
```

Comment: btw: that logic should rather be part of your class (like public method say `isValid()` or `isComplete()`, `whatever()`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create another method to check if any of fields is `null`:

```dart
class Job {
  String id;
  String jobTitle;
  String updatedAt;
  String createdAt;
  Job({this.id, this.jobTitle, this.updatedAt, this.createdAt});

  factory Job.fromMap(Map data) {
    return Job(
      id: data['id'],
      jobTitle: data['jobTitle'],
      updatedAt: data['updatedAt'],
      createdAt: data['createdAt'],
    );
  }

  bool checkIfAnyIsNull() {
    return [id, jobTitle, updatedAt, createdAt].contains(null);
  }
}

void main() {
  Job _job = Job();

  // Comment any of these fields and you would get [true].
  // [false] means all fields are set.
  _job.id = "1";
  _job.jobTitle = "Developer";
  _job.createdAt = "27-11-2019";
  _job.updatedAt = "28-11-2019";

  if(_job.checkIfAnyIsNull()){
    print("Not all fields are set");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the Best Approach is to assign a null to the Object

```
_job = null ;
```

and then add the new Details